# Cloud function doesn't send messages to PubSub

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

### Summary:

Hello, i'm using a cloud function as async background worker triggered by PubSub.
I've got 2 cloud functions, the 1st one will make a request to Cloud SQL then, for each result, will send this result to PubSub. and the 2nd one will be triggered when a message (so one of the result in the database) is sent to PubSub.

### Error:

Sometime (completly random) the 1st cloud function doesn't send any messages after the SQL request and i've got 0 error in log, there is just nothing.

### Questions:

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Have I to try to acknowledge the message ? (I guess no cause' I saw in PubSub documentation that a CF triggered by PubSub acknowledge automatically the message)

Have I to try to send again the message ? but how can i know if i have to if i've got 0 error ?

### Code:

```js
//[requirements]
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const pubSubClient = new PubSub('<PROJECT_ID>');
const topicName = "<TOPIC_NAME>";
const topicPublisher = pubSubClient.topic(topicName)
//[requirements]


//[request]
  //make the setted request 
  conn.query(sql, (e,results) => {
    //if there is an error send it
    if(e) console.log(e)
    //for each result of the query, log it and publish it on PubSub
    results.forEach(function (element){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(element))
      msgPubSub(JSON.stringify(element))
    })
  })
//[request]

//[PubSub message publish fonction]
async function msgPubSub(data){
  const messageBuffer = Buffer.from(data)
  try {
    var futurePublish = await topicPublisher.publish(messageBuffer)
    console.log("Message id: " + futurePublish)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error while publishing message: ${error.message}`)
  }
}
//[PubSub message publish fonction]
```

### Logs:

when it's not working:
[image]

when it's working:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should convert your query function to this:

```
let results;
try {
    results = await conn.query(sql);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(`SQL Error: ${err.message}`);
    return;
}

// TODO Maybe you can place a check here whether `results` is array
// Or something like that
for(let result of results){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
    await msgPubSub(JSON.stringify(result))
}
```

It's nonsense to use await and callback together

Comment: ho yeah it's true, my bad !
i'll just use callback, i prefer this way :)

Comment: What about pubsub? Does it work more stable now?

Comment: Yeah it's way stable now ! Thanks a lot :) 
and btw i learn about callback and await ^^